# Hospital healthcare clinic system

Tags: content-management-system, erp

I have been trying to find an open source or paid system for hospitals, clinics and in general for a healthcare.

do you know any please?

most of that I find is not supported or bad or not working

I want to integrate it with my call center.

thanks

Comment: do you mind to mark answer below as right answer, in absence of any other productive one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are interested on GNUHealth.

Have a look at their home page and project page:

- http://health.gnu.org/
- http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/health/